# Java String to Date unparsable date

Tags: java, string, parsing, date

This is the String I'm extracting the info from using a regex:

> 2823893a2f91c7507831f140dd7aa75e420477b0 - #0023922: Fixed the message
>   for defaulted bonds ; Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000

This is the code I use to extract the String and then try to make it into a Date:

```
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile(";\\s(.*)");
Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(s);
matcher3.find();
String t = matcher3.group(1).toString();
       try {
         Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy hh:mm a").parse(t);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

This should be the format of my input:

```
Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000
```

And what I want is to make a Date from the aforementioned string which looks like:

```
25/Oct/12 12:08 PM
```

But I keep getting these errors:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000"
Fixed the message for defaulted bonds0null
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at GitItem.cultivateGitItem(GitItem.java:42)
    at main.main(main.java:9)
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 25 11:52:39 2012 +0000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at GitItem.cultivateGitItem(GitItem.java:42)
    at main.main(main.java:9)
```

Comment: This looks like some output from a VCS... If `git`, why not use jgit? (edit: should read more; it is git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply remove the unwanted part:

```
String dateAsString = s.replaceAll(".*;\\s+","");
```

Then you need to DateFormat: one to parse the string and another one to output the correct format:

```
String s = "2823893a2f91c7507831f140dd7aa75e420477b0 - #0023922: Fixed the message for defaulted bonds ; Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000";
System.out.println("s = " + s);
String dateAsString = s.replaceAll(".*;\\s+","");
System.out.println("dateAsString = " + dateAsString);
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy X", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = parser.parse(dateAsString);
System.out.println("date = " + date);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

outputs:

```
s = 2823893a2f91c7507831f140dd7aa75e420477b0 - #0023922: Fixed the message for defaulted bonds ; Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000
dateAsString = Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000
date = Thu Oct 25 14:08:25 CEST 2012
25/Oct/2012 12:08 PM
```

Note: you need to use the appropriate locale to parse and print the month/day names

Comment: It gives me an error at this line:

`DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy X", Locale.getDefault());`

This is the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:575)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:500)
 at GitItem.cultivateGitItem(GitItem.java:44)
 at main.main(main.java:9)`

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: @Schadenfreude `X` is available in Java 7+. If you use an earlier version, you will get that exception.

Comment: However it should work with `Z` instead of `X`: `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern has to match the pattern of the incoming data, which it doesn't right now.

`SimpleDataFormat` can't read your mind, the pattern you are giving it doesn't match the format you are passing into `.parse()`.

`"dd/MMM/yy hh:mm a"` will never match `Thu Oct 25 12:08:25 2012 +0000`, you have to specify the exact pattern that the incoming data is in, this is very well documented in the JavaDocs.

Then you can change the pattern to what you want using `.applyPattern()` can call `.format()` to get the formatted output you want.